# Dependent Child can sponsor wife for UK family visa?

Tags: uk-visa, dependent-visa

My father has Italian nationality and is living in pre-settled status in UK. I am nearly 30 of age, and I received pre-settled status as a dependent child under EEA regulation 2016. My baby received EU settlement scheme family permit visa as a grandchild.

But my wife was refused an EEA family permit because of my father's low income. My baby can not fly to the UK without mother.

What type of visa I can try? Any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
Here I Explain details.

My father , My mother and my younger sister is living in uk with 
pre settle status as they have italian citizenship.
Usually My father works.
But also depend on universal credit because of low income.
Now he is not working because of illnes and admitted into hospital.
I was living in italy so I have Italian permanent resident card
I was traveled to Uk with my father. The Uk Border leave me to enter
as per EEA regulation 2016 articale 20. However I applied for Uk resident
card under eu settlement scheme as a dependent adult child.And I showed that 
I am studying at university in Bangladesh. And I got pre settlement status.
Currently I am in Bangladesh and near to finish my Graduate. I applied for my 
baby and got visa under eu settlement scheme as dependent grandchild of my Father.
I applied for my wife as dependent daughter in law for eea family permit but become refused.
I provided supporting documents that show my wife is a student also, depends on my father , living 
in my father property, does not work and must travel with my daughter.

But nothing. In refuse letter the entry clearance officer said that my father income is low,
IF my wife goes to uk she will be burden of social benefit.
Now I want to know If I go to UK and work , Can I sponsor my wife for spouse visa?

Comment: I have edited the title and body of your question to improve their clarity while not changing the meaning. If you disagree with my changes, you may revert the text to what you originally posted using the "edit" button found below the question's text.

Comment: How are you dependent on your father if his income is low?  Do you live with your father? Did your wife live with your father ever?  Would she live with him in the UK?  Where does she live now?  I think your best bet is to challenge the refusal. If your wife is (along with you) actually dependent on your father then the size of his income should not matter.  Can you edit the question to include an image of the refusal letter with identifying information blacked out?

Comment: @phoog  Answering your question I update my question with details .

Comment: @infomasud please post an image of the letter.  Something sounds off, because your father's income and your wife's allegedly being a burden on social services should not be relevant to an EEA family permit application.  Your wife could in theory enter the UK with a tourist visa, but in these circumstances it's almost certain that the visa application would be refused.

Comment: @phoog I tried the best option. If not possible i will try tuorist visa. then i will work and in future can apply for spouse visa. however here is a link of refusal letter text  . [ https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HsCh_torOTpGQLvgmDpVFpLezWS4blPF ]

Comment: @phoog do you have any suggestion for me ? i want to know also , can I apply for tourist visa after this kind of refusal ?